# Pandas find maximum number of weeks continuous drop in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe like below. I wanted to find out maximum how many weeks **continuous** drop by ID and Product wise.

```
import pandas as pd

raw_data = {'ID': ['101', '101', '101','101', '101', '101', '102', '102', '102', '102','102', '103', '103', '103', '103','104', '104', '104', '104','104','104'],
            'product':['x','x','x','x','x','x','z','z','z','z','z','y','y','y','y','x','x','x','x','x','x'],
            'Week': ['201828','201829','201830','201831','201832','201833','201829','201830','201831','201832','201830','201831','201832','201833','201830','201831','201832','201833','201834','201835','201836'],
    'Orders': ['-15%','-4%','-6%','6%','-10%','15%','-26%','-15%','-56%','-15%','-4%', '5%', '-10%', '-10%', '15%', '-20%', '-11%','10%', '-15%', '-20%','-26%']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(raw_data, columns = ['ID','product','Week','Orders'])
```

Wanted Output:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way using `cumsum` create addtional keys

```
s=df2['Orders'].str.contains('-')

df2[s].groupby([df2.ID,(~s).groupby(df2['ID']).cumsum(),df2['product']]).size().max(level=[0,2])
Out[202]: 
ID   product
101  x          3
102  z          5
103  y          2
104  x          3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks i want to add product also. this giving error when i tried to add product s=df2['Orders'].str.contains('-')

df2[s].groupby([df2['ID','product'],(~s).groupby(df2['ID','product']).cumsum()]).size().max(level=0)

Comment: @KumarAK `df2[s].groupby([df2.ID,(~s).groupby(df2['ID']).cumsum(),df2['product']]).size().max(level=[0,2])`